# How to push multiple branches from multiple commits?

Tags: git, github

I never used `git` before `GitHub` released the Windows app, so I've never used it in command line.

So here's my situation:
I did some commits on `master`, then switched branch and did some commits there too. All without pushing to GitHub.
When I then clicked `sync` in the the windows app (which I assume does `git push`), to my surprise, all my commits were pushed to my new branch - even the commits I made while I was in `master`.

Since this is the behavior of the windows app, I guess I have to use the command line.
What is the correct `git push` command to push the commits to the correct branches on the remote?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

To push all branches (refs under refs/heads), use the following command (where origin is your remote):

```
git push origin --all
```

---

You can also set [`push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html) to `matching` in your config to push all branches having the same name on both ends by default. For example:

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

Since Git 2.0 the default is `simple` which is the the safest option.

Comment: To clarify the above comment, as per push's documentation: "The special refspec `:` (or `+:` to allow non-fast-forward updates) directs Git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side.".

Answer (score 108):

If you want to push several specific branches (for example branch1 and branch2) you can use:

```
git push origin branch1 branch2
```

In Git >= 2.4 this operation can be done atomically (i.e. if it fails to push any of the branches specified nothing will be pushed):

```
git push --atomic origin branch1 branch2
```

Answer (score 9):

`git push origin` will push from all tracking branches up to the remote by default.

`git push origin my-new-branch` will push just your new branch.

I don't believe there is anything simple or possible to do accidentally that would push commits from two different branches up to the same branch and do the merge on the remote.

I would guess that the new branch had the commits from master in it's history.  To see if that is true, run `git log my-new-branch` locally and see if those commits were in your history.

If so, when you "switched branches" you probably branched off of master *after* the new commits were made, so the new branch had all of the commits in the history, no just the ones unique to that branch.

Comment: I am not sure about your last suggestion, I'd say the command is simply `git push origin branchOne anotherBranch`

Comment: I think that newer versions of git don't push all tracking branches: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13148313/586086

Answer (score 5):

Late answer but I am gonna share my solution that worked for me.

Finally my `/foo/.git/config` file looks like:

```
[core]
    ...

[remote "dev"]
    url = http://dev.foobar.com/foo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dev/*
[remote "pro"]
    url = http://pro.foobar.com/foo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/pro/*

[remote "all"]
    url = http://dev.foobar.com/foo.git
    url = http://pro.foobar.com/foo.git

[http]
    postBuffer = 524288000
```

And command;

```
git push all --all
```

Credits: **[Pushing to Multiple Git Repositories Simultaneously](http://web.archive.org/web/20130915212058/http://www.jeetworks.org/node/22)**

Comment: Why do you have `url` twice under `[remote "all"]`?

Comment: Link now broken.

Comment: @MiniGod he has the url thwice that the remote "all" is pushed to both urls simultaneously

Answer (score 4):

You can do a

```
 git branch | grep "<pattern>" | xargs git push
```

Replace the `<pattern>` with a regular expression to match your branch names and that’s it.

You can add `--set-upstream origin` if it is your first commit for this branch

Comment: This one almost worked for me but I had to tweak it a bit: `git branch --format='%(refname:short)' --list 'pattern*' | xargs git push origin`, the format argument is to remove the asterisk in the output. Also I replaced grep pipe by using --list argument. But this is not required. I needed the origin (the remote) argument in push command otherwise I got a "branch_name does not appear to be a git repository" error

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that is you have bending changes (in your working-tree) and switch branches those changes may persist over. Then you do add/commit/push and are surprised.