# Does "git push" push all commits from other branches?

Tags: git, git-push

If I have many unpushed commits spread among many branches in my local repo, what happens if I type `git push`? Will all of those commits be pushed or only those which belong to the current branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git push multiple branches from multiple commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000563/git-push-multiple-branches-from-multiple-commits)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It also depends on your **push policies (`git config push.default`)**.

As I explain in "[git - push current vs. push upstream (tracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751847/6309)", only the "matching" policy pushes more than the current branch.

> **push all branches having the same name on both ends**.
>   This makes the repository you are pushing to remember the set of branches that will be pushed out (e.g. if you always push `maint` and `master` there and no other branches, the repository you push to will have these two branches, and your local `maint` and `master` will be pushed there).

With that policy, only a simple `git push` is enough to push all (matching) branches.
Without that policy, a `git push --all` is necessary to *force* all branches to be pushed.

Comment: @Honey a `git push --all`, by pushing all branches, would also push all commits.

Comment: even commits on detached heads?

Comment: @Honey No: as illustrated here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/35736116/6309), detached heads would not be part if a push.

Answer (score 32):

No, `git push` only pushes commits from current local branch to remote branch that you specified in command.

You *can* tell git to push all branches by setting the `--all` argument

See the [command description](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)