# Is it possible to push a commit which is not in any branch in git?

Tags: git, git-push

Locally I can commit without any branch active, i.e. after checking out to a commit but not a branch. Is it possible to push this commit which is not in any branch to remote?

EDIT: I'm just wondering theoretically how would git handle pushing a "no-branch" or is pushing only possible with branches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making a git push from a detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736116/making-a-git-push-from-a-detached-head)

Comment: You can push *tags*, which I believe do not necessarily have to be attached to a branch.

Comment: @ObsidianAge - I don't think that's a duplicate as this question is explicitly asking if you can push the commit _without_ creating a branch.

Comment: Even if you could push a commit like that, note that it would be automatically deleted in about 30 days (depending on the server's configuration) because it'd be an orphaned commit. *Something* must reference a commit otherwise it's cleaned up after some period of time.

Answer (score 6):

When you do

```
git push <remote> <source>:<destination>
```

The `<source>` can be a commit, yes.

The `<destination>`, however, is a bit more tricky. Take it from the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203) :

> It’s possible to push any type of object to any namespace outside of refs/{tags,heads}/*. In the case of tags and commits, these will be treated as if they were the commits inside refs/heads/* for the purposes of whether the update is allowed.

So basically, you mostly push only to remote *branches*, but yes you can push commits, as long as moving from their current ref to the one you're pushing is a fast-forward merge.

Comment: Also from the doc: "*The <src> is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as master~4 or HEAD*"

Comment: Yes, I forgot to quote for the first part of my answer and it sounded like an assertion. Thanks for the addition :-)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that whatever name you issue, when you run `git push <hash>:<name>`, that name is given to the other Git to decide whether to allow it. GitHub allows `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` names but not `refs/pull/` names, for instance. Other receivers will have different sets of rules they enforce.

Comment: Did `git push origin d8c1e3` and got `fatal: d8c1e3 cannot be resolved to branch.`, did `git push origin d8c1e3:d8c1e3` and got `error: unable to push to unqualified destination: d8c1e3
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.`

Comment: @epp why are you trying to push commit hashes?

Comment: @RomainValeri to verify your answer

Comment: @epp Wow sorry, it's been a while since this thread and I had forgotten part of it, ok nevermind.