# Push git commit without a branch

Tags: git

In Git, I can use the following syntax to push a specific commit to a specific remote branch:

```
git push remote COMMIT:branchname
```

However, this ONLY works if there is a local branch which references COMMIT. Is there a way to do this push for a commit, even if there is no ref that refers to it?

Comment: What does *"local branch which references COMMIT"* mean? If a commit isn't referenced it doesn't exist in GIT

Comment: That's not quite correct, @Edward. Actually, the restriction was that the remote branch had to exist to be able to push.... but I'm not even sure this restriction is true anymore.

Comment: @Liam, I guess he means that there has to be a branch pointing to the revision.

Comment: Directly or indirectly? This sounds like your have an orphaned commit your trying to force into the graph. This questions needs **a lot** more context

Comment: Once you do `git init` you'll have a local branch called master.. There's no way to do commits without having a default branch..

Comment: @Baklap4 That's not relevant. In this scenario there are already local branches and local commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to push a commit which is not in any branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130311/is-it-possible-to-push-a-commit-which-is-not-in-any-branch-in-git)

Comment: The answer on that question is worse though; the answer doesn't actually answer the question and you have to look at comments for the answer.

Comment: If you’re in a headless state just create a branch and push. Then delete it afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full spelling of a branch name is `refs/heads/branchname`. When you push, if the destination ref doesn't begin with `refs/` Git figures out what prefix you meant by looking at what you're pushing. But if there's a bare commit there, it has nothing to go on, so you have to specify the full spelling of the destination ref explicitly:

```
git push origin 54adf:refs/heads/branchname
```