# Created a branch called HEAD by accident

Tags: git

I created a local branch in git called test1234 and pushed it to origin through Eclipse.
But I did something really wrong because I got an email, "superbobbay pushed new branch HEAD" when I was expecting "superbobbay pushed new branch test1234"

`git branch -r` shows origin/HEAD->origin/master

`cat .git/HEAD` just returns a commit string "8da516...."

Is there a way to revert this? I can't seem to fetch/rebase anymore.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736116/making-a-git-push-from-a-detached-head

Comment: I don't think I have a detached HEAD though. When I do a git status I get "On branch master. Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged." Oh man, this is baddd.

Comment: Are you using github ?

Comment: I'm on gitlab. Is there a way to back out this change?

Comment: This is technically possible, because a branch is simply a reference whose name starts with `refs/heads/`. So `refs/heads/HEAD` is a valid branch name whose short name is `HEAD`. It is, however, far more likely that you simply pushed your existing commits to `origin/master`, so that `origin/master` has the same commits as your local branch named `test1234`.

Comment: @bobbay You can use the gitlab ui to go and manually delete the branch there. Then re-clone the repo and you'll have no trace of that branch.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, I deleted the branch on gitlab UI and fetched/rebased, things are back to normal. I don't think I need to re-clone though. Seems ok. WHEW! Thank you!

Comment: @bobbay I have added the solution as a answer, kindly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you've already pushed to origin, you can goto gitlab GUI -> Repository settings & delete the branch from there.

Then you can simply re-clone the repo, or delete the branch from your local repo to remove its existence completely.

Kudos !

Answer (score 2):

Go to .git directory in your local working copy, go to the `refs` subdir and find a file called like your branch - `HEAD` - and delete it.

Mind that I' writing about `refs` subdir. Not `logs` not root `.git`.